# recurring payment using creditcard PCI complient solution

Tags: paypal, credit-card, recurring-billing, pci-compliance

I wanted to implement payment mechanism using paypal payment gateway, following are the requirements.

1. recurring billing [monthly].
2. System should accept Cards [Non paypal user should able to do recurring payment]

I have gone through various approaches given in samples.

1. DoDirect payment :  Solution has to be PCI Compliant [I am really not sure what I should take care of.]
2. Express Checkout : This does not satisfy my 2nd requirement, i.e buyer has to have Paypal account [Please correct me if I am wrong here]

I come across many other solutions like "Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution" too.
another finding is:
The use of recurring payments with direct payment may incur additional fees.

Can anybody suggest me simpler approach to satisfy above requirements, i.e. **Credit card support, recurring payment and no issues related to PCI compliance**.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm assuming you mean "recurring" wherever you say "recursive" :) You should look into [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com) (note: I work there) instead of PayPal if you want to accept credit cards. They offer two methods for PCI compliance, TR and CSE, and they do monthly recurring billing.

Comment: yes, I mean recurring :)
corrected.

Comment: Hi @agf, do you offer a hosted solution like an IFRAME I could embedd on our site so that if takes off the transmission responsibilities off our shoulders?

Comment: @WooDzu Get it touch with us ([contact info](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact))!